# Functions and loops in C

Tags: c, function, for-loop, while-loop

How can I make this function `odddigits` to return each and every value the `while` and `for` loops calculates of the variable `odd` at every iteration for `i`? Thanks in advance.

This worked fine when I the wrote the loops inside main function but when I abstracted out the loops into another function it doesn't seem to return all values from the loops, but returns only the last value once all iterations are completed.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int odddigits(long cardnum);
long odd;

int main(void) {
    long n = get_long("Number: ");
    printf("%i\n", odddigits(n));
}

int odddigits(long cardnum) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 16; i += 2) {
        long x = pow(10, i);
        odd = cardnum % x;

        while (odd >= 10) {
            odd = odd / 10;
        }
     }
     return odd;
}
```

Comment: You can't the way you have it written. A function only returns one value. You could return a dynamically allocated array of integers or do something where you repeatedly call the function and maintain the previous state with a pointer, but both are complex. You should also avoid using `pow` for integer calculations. It may not always do what you expect. The easiest solution would be to move the code back into main and print each digit as you calculate it.

Comment: @Yashita Sharma it is not clear what you re trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in the number `123456789` digit `1` is zero and `9` is 8 and you want to print digits having odd numbers:

```
int main(void)
{
    int arr[20];
    size_t size = 0;
    printf("%zu\n", size = odddigits(arr, 1234567));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) printf("[%zu] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
}

size_t odddigits(int *buff, long n)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    long mask = 1;
    long wrk = n / 10;
    while(wrk)
    {
        mask *= 10;
        wrk /= 10;
    }
    while(mask)
    {
        if(size % 2) buff[size / 2] = abs(n / mask);
        size++;
        n %= mask;
        mask /= 10;
    }
    return size / 2;
}
```

1. You need to return array of integers.
2. Do not use math functions like pow when you deal with integer numbers. It almost never works
3. Format your code

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit more complicated, as the other commenters already suggested. Here are my suggestions.
Caveat: no checks, no balances, you have to add them all yourself before going in production!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    /* No need for math.h */
    
    /* For strtol() because I don't want to copy get_long() here */
    #include <stdlib.h>
    /* For CHAR_BIT */
    #include <limits.h>
    
    long odddigits(long cardnum);
    long odddigits_single(long cardnum);
    long *odddigits_array(long cardnum);
    
    /* Input from commandline now! */
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
       long n, copy;
       long *array;
    
       if (argc < 2) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s integer\n", argv[0]);
          return 1;
       }
       /* You have to use get_long() here */
       n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    
       puts("Not really working as intended, I presume?");
       printf("oddigits %ld\n\n", odddigits(n));
    
       /* We need to work on copy now because we change the input */
       copy = n;
       puts("\nRecursive");
       while (copy > 0) {
          printf("odddigits single %ld\n", odddigits_single(copy));
          copy /= 10;
       }
    
       puts("\nArray");
       array = odddigits_array(n);
    
       /* This will print the whole array not only the digits */
       for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
          printf("odddigits array %ld\n", array[i]);
       }
    
       puts("\nArray, odd digits [1,3,5,7,9] only:");
       /* This will search the whole array not only the digits */
       for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
          long tmp = array[i];
          if ((tmp & 0x1L) == 1) {
             printf("odddigits array %ld\n", tmp);
          }
       }
       free(array);
    
       return 0;
    }
    
    /* You are returning a long */
    long odddigits(long cardnum)
    {
       /* No need for a global variable */
       long odd = 0;
       /* No need for pow() */
       long x = 1;
       /* No need for iterations */
       /* for (int i = 1; i < 16; i+=2) { */
       while (x < cardnum) {
          /*
              This will overflow at one point (prob. throwing SIGFPE "Floating point exception" )
              It is a better idea to shrink cardnum.
           */
          x *= 10;
          odd = cardnum % x;
          printf("odd in for loop: %ld\n", odd);
          while (odd >= 10) {
             odd = odd/10;
             printf("odd in while loop: %ld\n", odd);
          }
       }
       return odd;
    }
    
    long odddigits_single(long cardnum)
    {
       long odd = 0;
       odd = cardnum % 10;
       return odd;
    }
    
    
    long *odddigits_array(long cardnum)
    {
       long odd = 0;
    
       /* this type is way too large for a single digit, you might use "char" instead */
       long *array;
       /* Iterator for array */
       int i=0;
    
       /* Assuming 64 bit "long" */
       array = calloc(20, sizeof(long) * 20 * CHAR_BIT);
       if (array == NULL) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed to allocate %zu bytes\n", (sizeof(long) * 20 * CHAR_BIT));
          return NULL;
       }
       while (cardnum > 0) {
          /* Get smalles digit */
          odd = cardnum % 10;
          /* gather digit */
          array[i] = odd;
          i++;
          /* Shrink cardnum to get next digit */
          cardnum /= 10;
       }
       return array;
    }
```

Try it:

```
    $ ./so_odddigits 1234
    Not really working as intended
    odd in for loop: 4
    odd in for loop: 34
    odd in while loop: 3
    odd in for loop: 234
    odd in while loop: 23
    odd in while loop: 2
    odd in for loop: 1234
    odd in while loop: 123
    odd in while loop: 12
    odd in while loop: 1
    oddigits 1
    
    
    Recursive
    odddigits single 4
    odddigits single 3
    odddigits single 2
    odddigits single 1
    
    Array
    odddigits array 4
    odddigits array 3
    odddigits array 2
    odddigits array 1
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    odddigits array 0
    
    Array, odd digits [1,3,5,7,9] only:
    odddigits array 3
    odddigits array 1
```

But you have been warned:

```
    $ ./so_odddigits 123456789123123123123
    Not really working as intended
    odd in for loop: 7
    odd in for loop: 7
    odd in for loop: 807
    odd in while loop: 80
    odd in while loop: 8
    odd in for loop: 5807
    odd in while loop: 580
    odd in while loop: 58
    odd in while loop: 5
    odd in for loop: 75807
    odd in while loop: 7580
    odd in while loop: 758
    odd in while loop: 75
    odd in while loop: 7
    odd in for loop: 775807
    odd in while loop: 77580
    odd in while loop: 7758
    odd in while loop: 775
    odd in while loop: 77
    ...
    odd in for loop: 9223372036854775807
    odd in while loop: 922337203685477580
    odd in while loop: 92233720368547758
    odd in while loop: 9223372036854775
    odd in while loop: 922337203685477
    odd in while loop: 92233720368547
    odd in while loop: 9223372036854
    odd in while loop: 922337203685
    odd in while loop: 92233720368
    odd in while loop: 9223372036
    odd in while loop: 922337203
    odd in while loop: 92233720
    odd in while loop: 9223372
    odd in while loop: 922337
    odd in while loop: 92233
    odd in while loop: 9223
    odd in while loop: 922
    odd in while loop: 92
    odd in while loop: 9
    Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

The rest, tracking the amount of digits gathered, error handling etc. pp., is left for you. It is a quick hack and might have a bug lurking somewhere.

Another trick, for whatever reason rarely taught, is the "dripping" method: one digit per function call.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    long odddigits_single_static(long cardnum);
    
    /* Input from commandline now! */
    int main(void)
    {
       long n=12345678901, t;
    
       puts("\nSingle shots");
       /* Another method */
       while ((t = odddigits_single_static(n)) > 0) {
          printf("odddigits single shots %ld\n", t);
       }
       /* Check if reset worked: */
       puts("\nSingle shots second time");
       /* Another method */
       while ((t = odddigits_single_static(n)) > 0) {
          printf("odddigits single shots second time %ld\n", t);
       }
       return 0;
    }
    
    long odddigits_single_static(long cardnum)
    {
       static long odd = 0;
       static long n = -1;
    
       if (n < 0l) {
          n = cardnum;
       }
       do {
          if (n == 0l) {
             odd = 0l;
             n = -1l;
             return -1l;
          }
          odd = n % 10l;
          n /= 10l;
       } while ((odd & 0x1l) == 0);
    
       return odd;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`oddigits()` will execute each for-loop, and after all loops are finished will return the last `odd` value, which is printed by the main function.

Maybe think about the placement of your `printf`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using printf here just to verify whether the function is returning correct values. Actually I want to later use the values of this variable in further calculations.

Comment: You can only return a single value from a function, so in your case only the last value of `odd` will be returned, after the for-loop is finished. 
You probably want to provide an array to the for-loop in order to save each calculated odd value.
If you want to make your values available in your main-function you will need to set up the array in your main, and provide odddigits() with a reference/pointer to that array.